# Post-hoc test for LMM with interaction terms

Tags: r, lme4, lsmeans

I've defined an lmer model in R with 2 fixed interacting effects, and three random effects. The first fixed effect, 'A' is categorical, whilst the second fixed effect 'B' is continuous:

```
library(lme4)
model1<- lmer(log(response)~A*B+(1|random1)+(1|random2)+(1|random3), data=Data)
```

I have tried to use lsmeans (now known as emmeans):

```
lsmeans(model1, pairwise~A*B, adjust="tukey")
```

and I have also tried to use glht:

```
summary(glht(model1, linfct = mcp(A*B ="Tukey")))
```

but neither of these options work.

I'm an R-novice. How might perform a post-hoc test on my LMM?